# Is there something wrong with my video code?

Tags: html, video-encoding

```
<div id="div1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
  <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="C:\Users\Trent Terrill\Desktop\Website Stuff\Media\video.ogg" type="video/ogg"/>
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```

It won't work in any browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, ...

  > The controls attribute is a boolean attribute. If present, it indicates that the author has not provided a scripted controller and would like the user agent to provide its own set of controls.

  (See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-media-controls)
- Second ...

  Using a "Windows-style" path like

  ```
  src="C:\Users\Trent Terrill\Desktop\Website Stuff\Media\video.ogg"
  ```

  could be a problem for the browser. Try to setup a local webserver (e.g. Apache) and convert your path to a URL.

Comment: It's been a while since I last used Windows, but `file:///C:/Users/Trent...` would possibly work. Although I wouldn't recommend it as a solution, particularly.